# Upload Files In RAZOR With jQuery Uploadify

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to upload image through Uploadify.

when uploading start the given error show.

**error :** *IO Error*

can you people help me about this error.

My code is given below:

**these directive i have include in my project.**

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js")"></script>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/uploadify.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.uploadify.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**JS:**

```
$(window).load(
            function() {
                $("#fileuploader").fileUpload({
                        'uploader': '/Scripts/uploader.swf',
                        'cancelImg': '/images/cancel.png',
                        'buttonText': 'Select Image',
                        'script': 'ShowClientQuotation/Upload',
                        'folder': '/images',
                        'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
                        'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
                        'multi': false,
                        'auto': true
                    });
            }
);
```

**html:**

```
<div id="fileuploader"></div>
```

**My Controller Name**: *ShowClientQuotation*

```
public string Upload(HttpPostedFileBase fileData)
        {
            var fileName = this.Server.MapPath("~/images/UserProfilePic/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileData.FileName));
            fileData.SaveAs(fileName);

            return "ok";
        }
```

Comment: Can you give more information about the error?  Where does it happen?  Is there a stack trace or other useful information?

Comment: @UmairNoor: That doesn't help.  What line of code throws the error?  What other information is included with the error?  What are the states of the objects when the error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

add setting in jquery **'fileDataName': 'fileData'**

`

```
$("#fileuploader").fileUpload({
                        'uploader': '/Scripts/uploader.swf',
                        'cancelImg': '/images/cancel.png',
                        'buttonText': 'Select Image',
                        'script': 'ShowClientQuotation/Upload',
                        'folder': '/images',
                        'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
                        'fileExt': '.jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png',
                        'multi': false,
                        'auto': true,
                       'fileDataName': 'fileData',
                    });
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Please check your folder path which you have given in 'folder' option. IO error comes only when Uploadify cannot file the folder/directory path where file should be stored.